# Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE9ditos...' with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am inserting data from CSV to database.

While i am trying to insert this row

```
2 créditos,,,,R,75,,
```

into my database i am getting this error Mysql::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE9ditos...' for column 'message' at row 1: .

Comment: What character encoding have you set on the connection/database table?

Comment: I'm guessing the data is coming from an HTML page - is the page encoding also set to UTF8?

Comment: @middaparks Data is coming from CSV files. I have no idea about page encoding that we have to set UTF8 or not. We are using flex as front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
Iconv.iconv('UTF-8','MS-ANSI',"your_text").to_s
```

Answer (score 2):

Chances are the data in the CSV files is in "Windows-1252" format (especially if it's sourced via Excel).

I'm afraid I don't know Ruby/Rails that well, but hopefully [this code snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5367) should help. :-)